# Using links jump to target inside PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, jspdf

I want to navigate in pdf file but I don't have page number or exact offset position because data is not in fixed amount. Data is in structured form.
I want like this: http://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/pdf/sample-link_1.pdf#appendix-a

Click on Text" **Purchasing Assistance** " and goto target position.
This link has ID  **#appendix-a**   not page number.

Please give solution. Thanks...